# check all and uncheck all check boxes

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to click on the button btn and select all check boxes, then click on it again and it will uncheck all. but my code below will only check all and uncheck all once. why does it stop working?

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$("#btn").on("click", function () { 
       var $checkbox = $(".checkBoxClass");
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
 });
});

</script>
 <span id="btn">btn</span><br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox1" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox2" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox3" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox4" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox5" />
        <br />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what do you expect `!$checkbox.attr('checked')` to return? Because `$checkbox.attr('checked')` returns 'checked' or nothing.

You should use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) not `attr` for this as it's truey/falsy

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $("#btn").on("click", function () { 
       var $checkbox = $(".checkBoxClass");
       $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

so now `!$checkbox.prop('checked')` returns `true` or `false` which you can legitimately call `!` against

Comment: i was jfiddling before answering, and this is the correct answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/rKEHV/

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.checkBoxClass').each(function() {
        $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).removeAttr('checked') : $(this).attr('checked','checked');
    });
});
```